# find out if last site was same as origin

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am using custom history manipulation on my onepage application (with `history.pushState`). As the user presses the browser native back button the site does not reload (thus not displaying the right content). I fixed this by listening for a `window.onpopstate` event where Id just reruning the initation script.

This however causes the user to be stuck on my page since as he tries to go back I simply reload the page, disreguarding if the page he wants to go to is on the same origin as mine or not. I would like somewhat like this:

```
window.onpopstate = () => {
  if (/*Site is same origin*/) load();
  else {
    //do Nothing
  }
};
```

How would I approch this?

Comment: look into the referer from the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this using `document.referrer`, match it with your domain and then take action accordingly. More about this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).